# verificar e proteger uma thread em c++

Tags: c, c++, c++11, dev-c++

Tenho uma duvida sobre thread já vasculhei tudo que pude sobre o assunto e nao encontrei a solução para meu problema!

atualmente criei uma thread simples para limpar memória:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, test, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

função:

```
DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lpvParam) {
memo: 
   Sleep(10000);
   SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), 102400, 614400);
goto memo;  
}
```

minha dúvida é a seguinte:
existe alguma forma de proteger essa thread? e impedir que ela seja pausada com algum programa externo? como por exemplo o (Process Hacker 2)

exemplo:
caso a thread esteja rodando, retorna true, caso ela seja pausada de forma externa ou interrompida retorna false e fecha o programa com o ExitProcess()?